# I used Intent Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS) to prevent turning of phone while using my app but now I am not able to turn off outside the app

Tags: android

I used this code to hide my system dialog for turning off my phone. but after I closed my application system dialog still did not appear and was not able to turn off my phone even after my app is closed.
so I need an opposite of this code that will make system dialog appear again

```
 override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (!hasFocus) {
        val closeDialog = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog)
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the description hope it is more clear now

Comment: On Android 12 devices this call will no longer be honored.